# Angularjs $scope is not updated

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an angular-ionic-firebase application. I am struggling on an issue where I am unable to update a $scope in my html. My  must resolve {{uevent}} and update the html with the result of {{uevent}}. My html code is below.

```
**<ion-view view-title="{{uevent}}">**
<ion-tabs class="tabs-stable tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Buddies" icon="ion-ios-people" ng-   click="showBuddies(a)">
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Summary" icon="ion-navicon" ng-click="billSummary()">
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

my angular code is below. CurrUser is a factory. I've defined an empty $scope.uevent which I am expecting to update using a value returned from a factory.

```
var eventid = CurrUser.getEventid();
$scope.uevent = " ";

function updateEvent(desc) {
$scope.uevent = desc;
console.log($scope.uevent);// I am able to see the value returned from the factory. This function is executed below in the for loop.
};

// promise that returns a value from the factory - CurrUser.
CurrUser.getEventdesc(eventid).then(function (result) {
var description = result;
var desc;
for (var itemID in description) {
var tmp = description[itemID];
desc = tmp.Description; // This contains the value that must be updated to $scope.uevent
updateEvent(desc); // Calls the function defined above to update $scope.uevent.
};
});
```

I've been on this since last night without any clues. Any help is greatly appreciated and as always, thanks for your time.

UPDATE #1:(07 July)
When i added a timeout of 1 sec, the view was updated to the correct value.

```
function updateEvent(desc) {
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function () { 
        $scope.uevent = desc;
        })
    },1000);
    };
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 execution context when You work with AngularJS - `Angular Context` and `JavaScript Context`.
When you are changing the data in `AngularJS Context`, the `digest loop` begins and all data updates, but when you change data in the `JavaScript Context` (e.g setTimeout, setInterval and so on), Angular doesn't know about the changes so it doesn't update the data.
In JavaScript Context you must change your data in `scope.$apply()` method to run the `digest loop` manually.
So your code will look like

```
        var eventid = CurrUser.getEventid();
        $scope.uevent = " ";

        function updateEvent(desc) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
           $scope.uevent = desc;
        });

        console.log($scope.uevent);// I am able to see the value returned from the factory. This function is executed below in the for loop.
        };

        // promise that returns a value from the factory - CurrUser.
        CurrUser.getEventdesc(eventid).then(function (result) {
        var description = result;
        var desc;
        for (var itemID in description) {
        var tmp = description[itemID];
        scope.$apply(function(){
    desc = tmp.Description; // This contains the value that must be updated to $scope.uevent
       })

        updateEvent(desc); // Calls the function defined above to update $scope.uevent.
        };
        });
```

For more.If there is an Angular JS alternative, you must use it,because it runs te digest loop automatically(`$timeout` instead of `setTimeout()`, `$interval` instead of `setInterval()`)

Comment: :This gives me an error that the digest loop is already in progress.

Comment: @AjRev can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this; $apply is used to trigger $digest .

```
function updateEvent(desc) {
  $timeout(function(){
   $scope.uevent = desc;
   $scope.$apply();
},0)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your controller defined in the html? Or is it in your app.js. Anyways, for a start can you do a $scope.$apply in your updateEvent function?

```
function updateEvent(desc) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.uevent = desc;
   });
  console.log($scope.uevent);
};
```

I dont know what happens in your getEventDesc() method but if there is a non-angular ajax request or something, then it might need the $apply to trigger the digest cycle and update watchers.

### Detailed explanation below.

**Reference**: This awesome informative post -> https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

> AngularJS provides wrappers for common native JS async behaviors:
>
> Events => ng-click
>   Timeouts => $timeout
>   jQuery.ajax() => $http
>   This is just a traditional async function with a $scope.$apply() called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred.
>
> $scope.$apply() should occur as close to the async event binding as possible.
>
> Do NOT randomly sprinkle it throughout your code. If you are doing
>   if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply() it's because you are not high enough in the call stack.
>
> Whenever possible, use AngularJS services instead of native. If you're creating an AngularJS service (such as for sockets) it should have a $scope.$apply() anywhere it fires a callback.